# In FastAPI - Unable to make multiple UploadFile optional

Tags: list, file, upload, option-type, fastapi

I am trying to make `UploadFile` optional in FastAPI, in the process, I am able to make a single file optional, but got an error if I convert it to multiple files.

```py
# Making optional for single uploadfile
@app.post("/optional-file")
async def optionalFile(file: Optional[UploadFile] = File(None)):
    if not file:
        print("no file")
        return "no file"
    print(file.filename)
    return {"name": file.filename}

# Making optional for multiple uploadfile
@app.post("/optional-files")
async def optionalFiles(files: Optional[List[UploadFile]] = File(None)):
    if not files:
        print("no files")
        return "no files"
    print(file[0].filename)
    return {"name": file[0].filename}
```

and I am getting this error in return.

```json
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","files",0],"msg":"Expected UploadFile, received: <class 'str'>","type":"value_error"}]}
```

Thanks in advance for any sort of help provided.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with:

```
def get_files(files_list: List[Union[UploadFile, str]] = File(None)):
    if isinstance(files_list, str):
        files_list = []
```

I send '', if i have no files to send.